# Handling responses for difference POST in the same controller in RestKit

Tags: response, restkit

I want to write a method, in my method I need post two POST methods to 
my web service and get data json returned for every method. How can I
process response for separate post?
Ex: in my view, I have:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:joeBlow 
                                     delegate:self];  (1) 
   [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:joeBlow_1 
                                  delegate:self];  (2)
```

How can I handle response for (1) and (2) in the same controller. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood it right , but maybe use:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)loader willMapData:(inout id *)mappableData ?
```